# Ubuntu 17.10 gnome crashing on login

Tags: gnome, 17.10

I keep losing my gnome session every time I log in. I'd love to figure out what's going on and causing the crash but I'm very new to Gnome what with it only now being the default desktop for Ubuntu. This crash seems to happen every time I log back into my computer after locking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having been trying to customize gnome to what I liked, I had created a folder under `~/.local/share/gnome-shell` called `/extensions` and had filled it with an extension. Removing said folder fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be hell lot of bugs in 17.10 specially with gnome, so for now I suggest to use X or unity.

X:

click on wheel and select X at login.

Unity:

sudo apt install unity

select good old lightdm instead of gdm when prompted, reboot and choose unity at login.